# Unity App on Hololens Emulator stuck loading

Tags: unity-game-engine, emulation, hololens

I have Unity & Visual Studio & Hololens Emulator all playing nicely, but when I try to open the Unity app in my Hololens Emulator the app stays at the loading circle and Visual Studio stays at "A remote operation is taking longer than expected." Any tips?

Edit.
I needed to disable something called "Just My Code."

Answer (score 0):

You have to look in the debug output when starting up for what goes wrong (console output). One solution could be to regenerate the VisualStudio project, but that depends on the error message on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Just My Code."

If this is the problem you'll need to go back to Visual Studio after initiating the Unity app in the emulator and tell it to disable.